# Array Indexing vs Pointer Arithmetic Performance

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

I read about array indexing and pointer arithmetic today and have an idea that two are the same things (e.g. array indexing is a syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic).

Besides that some other people said array indexing is faster than pointer arithmetic. (??)

I come up with these two code pieces to test performance. I tested them in C# but I think it would be same in C or C++.

### Array Indexing

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n is size of an array
{
    sum += arr1[i] * arr2[i];
}
```

### Pointer Arithmetic

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n is size of an array
{
    sum += *(arrP1 + i) * *(arrP2 + i);
}
```

I ran the code pieces 1000 times with arrays have more than millions of integer. The result is unexpected to me. Pointer arithmetic is slightly faster (about %10) than array indexing.

Does the result seem correct? Is there any explanation to make it sense?

### Edit

I want to add generated assembly codes.

### Array Indexing

```
sum += arr1[i] * arr2[i]; // C# Code

 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
 cmp         dword ptr [eax+4],0  
 ja          00E63195  
 call        73EDBE3A  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+8]  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
 cmp         edx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
 jb          00E631A5  
 call        73EDBE3A  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+edx*4+8]  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
 cmp         dword ptr [edx+4],0  
 ja          00E631B7  
 call        73EDBE3A  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [edx+8]  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
 cmp         ecx,dword ptr [edx+4]  
 jb          00E631C7  
 call        73EDBE3A  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [edx+ecx*4+8]  
 add         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax
```

### Pointer Arithmetic

```
sum += *(arrP1 + i) * *(arrP2 + i); // C# Code

 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-28h],eax  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-28h]  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+edx*4]  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],edx  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [edx+ecx*4]  
 add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax
```

Comment: I'd say that in Clang or GCC I'd expect exactly identical results. Not being very familiar with C#, I don't know if there is a reasonable reason for it being slower in one case htan the other.

Comment: This is not a question about C or C++, this is a question about C# (where array accesses are bounds-checked, among other things)

Comment: @immibis Can bounds-checking make array indexing slower in C#? (and these two are same in C and C++)

Comment: @immibis: it seems if it were a C# question only the C and C++ tags shall be absent.

Comment: Bounds checking in general compiles very efficiently in .NET JIT land so I can't imagine it accounts for a 10% speed decrease for such a basic test. It basically becomes a fused operation and the compiler will be smart about structuring the check around a branch prediction miss, so the bounds check isn't likely to happen here. In a more complex sample it might be an issue but I wouldn't think it should be here. This is assuming the test was not run as a Debug build with zero optimizations.

Comment: In C++ it should have same speed (and it does at least in GCC). More, `a[i]` is **defined** to be identical to `*(a + i)` in Standard.

Comment: Oh and my comment alsonassumes you are running in 64 bit.. given the jitters ability to almost completely remove bounds checking from this sort of test (32 bit JITter is nowhere near as good)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I look at the generated assembly in VS for the two and array indexing has more instructions (more cmp and call instructions). It looks like bounds checking has an effect, even slightly.

Comment: Without optimization using pointers is generally better than using indexes.  But your example has not used pointers in a way that enables that benefit.  So you seem to be seeing a C# specific issue.  With optimization, the compiler often understands your code better when you use indexes than when you use pointers.  So indexes may end up more efficient even if they are inherently less.

Comment: @JSF How can I use pointers in an more efficient way than I do now?

Comment: @immibis Can you explain "among other things"?

Comment: @dewe More instructions isn't always an indicator of worse performance at the CPU level. Simple compare and jump instructions for example, can be fused at the CPU level to be very very efficient. What results do you get when you run this, as a Release build outside of a debugger?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I edited.

Answer (score 2):

The hand optimized pointer based code is:

```
int* arrP1 = arr1;
int* limitP1 = &arr1[n];
int* arrP2 = arr2;

for (; arrP1<limitP1; ++arrP1, ++arrP2) 
{
    sum += *arrP1 * *arrP2;
}
```

Be aware that compiler optimized code may be better than hand optimized code, and the hand optimization might disguise the behavior, preventing the compiler from optimizing, so it can make things worse.

So with a stupid enough compiler optimizer, we can expect the hand optimized pointer version to be better than an indexed version.  But you need much more expertise (plus examining generated code and profiling) to ever make doing something like this usefully in real code.

Also if reading either input array causes cache misses, the whole optimization of the code (whether you do it or the compiler does it) ends up being completely useless, because any near sane version has the same performance as any other near sane version with matching cache misses.

Comment: Does that actually generate better/faster code with any known compiler? Certainly the code snippets I posted does a similar transformation already.

Comment: I haven't tried a hand optimization that simplistic in over a decade.  I expect you would have trouble finding a current compiler in which the optimizer fails to make that kind of decision as well or better than you would.  But in more complicated code a very skilled programmer might make that choice better than even a current optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, in C++ the result is identical [and would be in C too]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int arr1[], arr2[];
const int n = 1000000;


int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n is size of an array
    {
        sum += arr1[i] * arr2[i];
    }

    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);

    int* arrP1 = arr1;
    int* arrP2 = arr2;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n is size of an array
    {
        sum += *(arrP1 + i) * *(arrP2 + i);
    }

    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
}
```

Compiling with `clang++ -O2 -S arrptr.cpp` gives this for the first loop:

```
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movq    $-4000000, %rax         # imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFFC2F700
    pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_1:                                # %vector.body
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movdqu  arr1+4000000(%rax), %xmm3
    movdqu  arr1+4000016(%rax), %xmm4
    movdqu  arr2+4000000(%rax), %xmm2
    movdqu  arr2+4000016(%rax), %xmm5
    pshufd  $245, %xmm2, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm2[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm3, %xmm2
    pshufd  $232, %xmm2, %xmm2      # xmm2 = xmm2[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm3, %xmm3      # xmm3 = xmm3[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm3
    pshufd  $232, %xmm3, %xmm3      # xmm3 = xmm3[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm3, %xmm2    # xmm2 = xmm2[0],xmm3[0],xmm2[1],xmm3[1]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm5, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm5[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm4, %xmm5
    pshufd  $232, %xmm5, %xmm3      # xmm3 = xmm5[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm4
    pshufd  $232, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm4, %xmm3    # xmm3 = xmm3[0],xmm4[0],xmm3[1],xmm4[1]
    paddd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    paddd   %xmm1, %xmm3
    movdqu  arr1+4000032(%rax), %xmm1
    movdqu  arr1+4000048(%rax), %xmm4
    movdqu  arr2+4000032(%rax), %xmm0
    movdqu  arr2+4000048(%rax), %xmm5
    pshufd  $245, %xmm0, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm0[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm1, %xmm0
    pshufd  $232, %xmm0, %xmm0      # xmm0 = xmm0[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm1, %xmm1      # xmm1 = xmm1[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm1
    pshufd  $232, %xmm1, %xmm1      # xmm1 = xmm1[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm1, %xmm0    # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0],xmm0[1],xmm1[1]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm5, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm5[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm4, %xmm5
    pshufd  $232, %xmm5, %xmm1      # xmm1 = xmm5[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm4
    pshufd  $232, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm4, %xmm1    # xmm1 = xmm1[0],xmm4[0],xmm1[1],xmm4[1]
    paddd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    paddd   %xmm3, %xmm1
    addq    $64, %rax
    jne .LBB0_1
```

The second loop does:

```
    pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movaps  (%rsp), %xmm2           # 16-byte Reload
    movss   %xmm2, %xmm0            # xmm0 = xmm2[0],xmm0[1,2,3]
    movq    $-4000000, %rax         # imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFFC2F700
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_3:                                # %vector.body45
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movdqu  arr1+4000000(%rax), %xmm3
    movdqu  arr1+4000016(%rax), %xmm4
    movdqu  arr2+4000000(%rax), %xmm2
    movdqu  arr2+4000016(%rax), %xmm5
    pshufd  $245, %xmm2, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm2[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm3, %xmm2
    pshufd  $232, %xmm2, %xmm2      # xmm2 = xmm2[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm3, %xmm3      # xmm3 = xmm3[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm3
    pshufd  $232, %xmm3, %xmm3      # xmm3 = xmm3[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm3, %xmm2    # xmm2 = xmm2[0],xmm3[0],xmm2[1],xmm3[1]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm5, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm5[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm4, %xmm5
    pshufd  $232, %xmm5, %xmm3      # xmm3 = xmm5[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm4
    pshufd  $232, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm4, %xmm3    # xmm3 = xmm3[0],xmm4[0],xmm3[1],xmm4[1]
    paddd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    paddd   %xmm1, %xmm3
    movdqu  arr1+4000032(%rax), %xmm1
    movdqu  arr1+4000048(%rax), %xmm4
    movdqu  arr2+4000032(%rax), %xmm0
    movdqu  arr2+4000048(%rax), %xmm5
    pshufd  $245, %xmm0, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm0[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm1, %xmm0
    pshufd  $232, %xmm0, %xmm0      # xmm0 = xmm0[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm1, %xmm1      # xmm1 = xmm1[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm1
    pshufd  $232, %xmm1, %xmm1      # xmm1 = xmm1[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm1, %xmm0    # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0],xmm0[1],xmm1[1]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm5, %xmm6      # xmm6 = xmm5[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm4, %xmm5
    pshufd  $232, %xmm5, %xmm1      # xmm1 = xmm5[0,2,2,3]
    pshufd  $245, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[1,1,3,3]
    pmuludq %xmm6, %xmm4
    pshufd  $232, %xmm4, %xmm4      # xmm4 = xmm4[0,2,2,3]
    punpckldq   %xmm4, %xmm1    # xmm1 = xmm1[0],xmm4[0],xmm1[1],xmm4[1]
    paddd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    paddd   %xmm3, %xmm1
    addq    $64, %rax
    jne .LBB0_3
```

Which, aside from loop labels and a couple of instructions before the actual loop is identical.

`g++ -O2 -S` gives a similarly identical set of loops, but not using SSE instructions and unrolling, so the loops are simpler:

```
.L2:
    movl    arr1(%rax), %edx
    addq    $4, %rax
    imull   arr2-4(%rax), %edx
    addl    %edx, %ebx
    cmpq    $4000000, %rax
    jne .L2
    movl    %ebx, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    movl    arr1(%rax), %edx
    addq    $4, %rax
    imull   arr2-4(%rax), %edx
    addl    %edx, %ebx
    cmpq    $4000000, %rax
    jne .L3
    movl    %ebx, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
```

Comment: @Zboson: Really? I see nothing that implies that the compiler does something to resulve such a problem. And that is not what the question was about, it's whether the compiler generates different code or not. It doesn't.  [I tried removing `extern` and sticking `n` in the `[]`, and it makes no difference in gcc at least]

Comment: Still makes no difference if I make `int *arr1, *arr2` either. This is because (at least in gcc) assumes "strict aliasing" (`-fstrict-aliasing`) when you enable `-O2`, so the compiler will assume that data does not alias. But for THIS particular case `-fno-strict-aliasing` makes no difference either.

Comment: Yes, because `y[i] = x[i]` writes to memory, which MAY be overwriting old data.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are pretty similar.

```
arr[i]
```

This line multiply i by sizeof decltype(*arr) and add it to arr. That mean a multiplication and a addition.

If you would like to improve performance with pointer arithmetic, something like following could be better:

```
for (auto p=&(arrP1[0]); p<&(arrP1[n]); p++) // n is size of an array
{
    sum += *p; // removed arrP2 for simplification, but can be achieved too.
}
```

This new way remove the need of the multiplication.

**EDITED to include alternative solutions:**

As @SimpleVar pointed, for readability, several nearly equivalent solutions could be selected, depending on the programmer preference.

```
auto p = arrP1;
for (var i=0; i<n; i++, p++) sum += *p;
```

or even

```
for (auto p=arrP1; p<arrP1+n; p++) sum += *p;
```

Using C++11, there is also another alternative which allow the compiler to decide how to implement (which we could assume a correct performance)

```
for (auto &p: arrP1) sum += p;
```

(for this last, arrP1 need to be standard container like std::array or a declared array: it cannot be a pointer, as the loop will not have knowledge of the array size)

Comment: or just `for (var i=0; i<n; i++, p++) sum += *p;`

Comment: Yes, for readability, there are several nearly equivalent solutions :-)
Also:
for (auto p=arrP1; p<arrP1+n; p++)